# multiple errors while trying to insert into sqlitedatabase

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am trying to create an app with an sqlitedatabase and then add some data(the user provides first and last name, age , id is autoincrement) to the fields of the database, but I am getting multiple errors and I cannot correct them , although I have tried to change my code multiple times. 
This is my code : 
1st Class: FirstActivity

```
package com.example.dit.hua.ergasia.firstactivity;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

public class FirstActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.first_activity_main);
Button button1 = findViewById(R.id.Button_1);    //save given data to database when the user clicks the button !
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //passing to variables what the user wrote !
                //FIRST NAME
                EditText editTextFirstName = findViewById(R.id.Edit_text_first_name);
                String First_name = editTextFirstName.getText().toString();

                final TextView TextViewFirstName_show_error = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.My_Text_view_first_name);
                if(First_name.isEmpty()) {
//                  Toast.makeText(FirstActivity.this, "First name field is empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    TextViewFirstName_show_error.setText(R.string.Text_view_first_name_error);
                }else {
                    TextViewFirstName_show_error.setText(R.string.show_blank);
                    TextViewFirstName_show_error.setText(First_name);
                }

                //LAST NAME
                EditText editTextLastName = findViewById(R.id.Edit_text_last_name);
                String Last_name  = editTextLastName.getText().toString();

                final TextView TextViewLastName_show_error = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.My_Text_view_last_name);
                if(Last_name.isEmpty()) {
                    TextViewLastName_show_error.setText(R.string.Text_view_last_name_error);
                }else {
                    TextViewLastName_show_error.setText(R.string.show_blank);
                    TextViewLastName_show_error.setText(Last_name);
                }

                //AGE
                EditText editTextAge = findViewById(R.id.Edit_text_age);   // find the EditText, then get its value and put it into variable
                String Age = editTextAge.getText().toString();


                int value=0;
                if (!"".equals(Age)){                                     //  Check if the EditText is empty.  If it is empty, do not try to convert the received value to int. Otherwise, the application will crash.
                    value=Integer.parseInt(Age);                          //parse the value to Integer
                }

                final TextView TextViewAge_show_error = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.My_Text_view_age);
                if(Age.isEmpty()) {        //  Age.length()==0   other way                          //  Check if the EditText is empty.
                    TextViewAge_show_error.setText(R.string.Text_view_age_error);                           //  show error
                }else {
                    TextViewAge_show_error.setText(R.string.show_blank);
                    TextViewAge_show_error.setText(Age);  //h Age krasarei !!!  //ELEGXOS
                }

DataContract datacontractobject = null;
               try {
                    datacontractobject = new DataContract(First_name, Last_name, value);   //cretaing an object every time that the user wants to save data
                }catch(Exception e ){
                    Log.d(TAG, "CREATE OBJECT DATACONTRACTOBJECT ", e);
                    e.getStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(FirstActivity.this, "object datacontract not created!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }finally{
                    Toast.makeText(FirstActivity.this, "object datacontract created!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


                //saving to database the data that the user wrote
                boolean didItWork = true;

                DBHelper entry = new DBHelper(FirstActivity.this);
                DBHelper RETURN = null;
                try {
                    RETURN = entry.open(FirstActivity.this);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(FirstActivity.this, "open error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d(TAG, "OPEN  ", e);
                    e.getStackTrace();
                }

                try {
 RETURN.createEntry(datacontractobject);    //insert
                    RETURN.close();

                }catch(Exception e) {
                    didItWork = false;
                    Toast.makeText(FirstActivity.this, "Your data were not saved in database!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d(TAG, "INSERT ", e);
                    e.getStackTrace();
                }finally
                {
                    if(didItWork) {
                        Toast.makeText(FirstActivity.this, "Your data were saved in database!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

          }
        });
```

Class: It is a contract class named DataContract

```
package com.example.dit.hua.ergasia.firstactivity;

public class DataContract {
    //One of the main principles of SQL databases is the schema: a formal declaration of how the database is organized.
    // The schema is reflected in the SQL statements that I use to create my database.
    // This class is a companion class, known as a contract class, which explicitly specifies the layout of my schema in a systematic and self-documenting way.
    int id;
    String lname;
    String fname;
    int age;

    public DataContract(int id, String lname, String fname, int age) {
        this.id = id;
        this.lname = lname;
        this.fname = fname;
        this.age = age;
    }


    public DataContract(String lname, String fname, int age) {
        this.lname = lname;
        this.fname = fname;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }
}
```

3rd Class: DBHelper for connection with the database and inserting data to databse

```
package com.example.dit.hua.ergasia.firstactivity;


import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements BaseColumns {


    public static String FIRST_NAME = "_FIRST_NAME";
    public static String LAST_NAME = "_LAST_NAME";
    public static String AGE  ;
    //public static String ID = "0" ;

    public static final String DB_NAME = "MY_DATABASE";
    public static final String DB_TABLE = "MY_DATABASE";         ///"PERSONAL_DATA";
    public static final int DB_VERSION =1;

    public DBHelper ourHelper;
    public final Context ourcontext = null;
    public SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;


     public DBHelper(@Nullable Context context) {       //pulic constructor: to create a helper object to create, open, and/or manage a database.
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);     //Context: to use for locating paths to the the database

    }
    //context        Context: to use for locating paths to the the database This value may be null.
    //name           String: of the database file, or null for an in-memory database This value may be null.
    //factory        SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory: to use for creating cursor objects, or null for the default This value may be null.
    //version        int: number of the database (starting at 1); if the database is older, onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase, int, int) will be used to upgrade the database; if the database is newer, onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase, int, int) will be used to downgrade the database



    // Here are some typical statements that create and delete a table:
    private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + DB_TABLE + " (" +
                    BaseColumns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    FIRST_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                    LAST_NAME + " TEXT, "  +
                    AGE + " INTEGER NOT NULL ) ";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {  //create database table

try {
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
}catch(Exception e){
    Log.d(TAG, "DB HELPER ONCREATE  ", e);
    e.getStackTrace();
    e.getCause();
    e.getMessage();
    e.getLocalizedMessage();
}
    }
 @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {}

 public long createEntry(DataContract contactsContract){     //insert
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        //ID is autoincrement
        try {
            contentValues.put(FIRST_NAME, contactsContract.getFname());
            contentValues.put(LAST_NAME, contactsContract.getLname());
            contentValues.put(AGE, contactsContract.getAge());
        }catch(Exception e ){Log.d(TAG, "DBHELPER CREATE ENTRY  ", e);}
        //in every column i want to add a new row
        //i have created an object type of DataContract, which contains a fname, a lname an an age , so I need getters to "take" fname, lname and age from that object and put them into database each in the column that belongs
        long number = 0;
        try{
             number =ourDatabase.insert(DB_TABLE, null , contentValues);
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "DBHELPER INSERT IN CREATE ENTRY ", e);
        }
        return number ;
    }

}
```

As I previously said, I am getting multiple errors in the logcat while the app is running , inserting into databse!
Those are :

```
**
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
**
** 2019-12-08 19:15:04.944 17665-17665/com.example.dit.hua.ergasia.firstactivity E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "null": syntax error **
** 2019-12-08 19:15:04.948 17665-17665/com.example.dit.hua.ergasia.firstactivity E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting null=9 _FIRST_NAME=vhjj _LAST_NAME=vhjvj
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "null": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO MY_DATABASE(null,_FIRST_NAME,_LAST_NAME) VALUES (?,?,?)  **
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:890)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:501)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1546)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1417)
        at com.example.dit.hua.ergasia.firstactivity.DBHelper.createEntry(DBHelper.java:129)
        at com.example.dit.hua.ergasia.firstactivity.FirstActivity$4.onClick(FirstActivity.java:165)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
2019-12-08 19:15:04.963 17665-17665/com.example.dit.hua.ergasia.firstactivity D/ContentValues: INSERT 
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.dit.hua.ergasia.firstactivity.DBHelper.close()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.dit.hua.ergasia.firstactivity.DBHelper.close(DBHelper.java:97)
        at com.example.dit.hua.ergasia.firstactivity.DBHelper.close(DBHelper.java:97)
        at com.example.dit.hua.ergasia.firstactivity.FirstActivity$4.onClick(FirstActivity.java:166)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)



2019-12-08 19:15:23.914 1621-1643/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-12-08 19:15:23.914 1621-1643/system_process W/android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1


2019-12-08 19:19:20.044 1621-1655/system_process E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}
2019-12-08 19:19:25.042 1621-1655/system_process I/WifiService: requestActivityInfo uid=1000
```

I am really new to android programming and it is difficult for me to understand what these errors mean and how to fix them. If anyone could help me , it would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Just update to use this. you are probably using the SQLiteDatabase object without initializing in your DBHelper class which is declared at class level. adding one line should work `ourDatabase = db;` in onCreate

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {  //create database table

try {
    ourDatabase = db;
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
}catch(Exception e){
    Log.d(TAG, "DB HELPER ONCREATE  ", e);
    e.getStackTrace();
    e.getCause();
    e.getMessage();
    e.getLocalizedMessage();
    }
}
```

The below statement is causing the null pointer exception because you are using it without initializing it.

`number =ourDatabase.insert(DB_TABLE, null , contentValues);`

use below to get an object of sqlite db from your DB helper class and pass it as an argument to the function. or update the class level variable using this.

```
 DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(getContext());

 ourDatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

**Edit**:
you have some sqlite db creation code inside the `onClick()`, find it and replace it with the below one.

Code to find :

```
    //start....
    DBHelper entry = new DBHelper(FirstActivity.this);
                DBHelper RETURN = null;
                try {
                    RETURN = entry.open(FirstActivity.this);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(FirstActivity.this, "open error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d(TAG, "OPEN  ", e);
                    e.getStackTrace();
                }

                try {
 RETURN.createEntry(datacontractobject);    //insert
                    RETURN.close();

                }catch(Exception e) {
                    didItWork = false;
                    Toast.makeText(FirstActivity.this, "Your data were not saved in database!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d(TAG, "INSERT ", e);
                    e.getStackTrace();
                }
    //end...
```

Code to replace :

```
// start...
DBHelper entry = new DBHelper(FirstActivity.this);
SQLiteDatabase database = entry.getWritableDatabase();             

try {
     entry.createEntry(datacontractobject,database);    //insert
     database.close();
}catch(Exception e) {
     didItWork = false;
     Toast.makeText(FirstActivity.this, "Your data were not saved in database!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     Log.d(TAG, "INSERT ", e);
     e.getStackTrace();
}
//end...
```

in DBHelper class update the required function as below because we have changed the signature above when calling so let's change it here as well.
Now your  **createEntry** method should look like this.

```
 public long createEntry(DataContract contactsContract, SQLiteDatabase database ){     //insert
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    //ID is autoincrement
    try {
        contentValues.put(FIRST_NAME, contactsContract.getFname());
        contentValues.put(LAST_NAME, contactsContract.getLname());
        contentValues.put(AGE, contactsContract.getAge());
    }catch(Exception e ){Log.d(TAG, "DBHELPER CREATE ENTRY  ", e);}
    //in every column i want to add a new row
    //i have created an object type of DataContract, which contains a fname, a lname an an age , so I need getters to "take" fname, lname and age from that object and put them into database each in the column that belongs
    long number = 0;
    try{ 
         //changed the db variable now to method parameter instead of class one
         number = database.insert(DB_TABLE, null , contentValues);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG, "DBHELPER INSERT IN CREATE ENTRY ", e);
    }
    return number ;
}
```

Comment: where sould I add those two lines?  
DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(getContext());

 database = dbHelper.getWritableDa

Comment: @vikaskumer       where sould I add those two lines? DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(getContext()); database = dbHelper.getWritableDa –

Comment: In your Activity where you are doing `RETURN = entry.open(FirstActivity.this);` use the above 2 lines mentioned.

Comment: @StillLearning updated the code check if it helps. you have to make sure that nothing is null before calling any operation on the object of sqlite db

Comment: @vikaskumer Thanks a lot foe the update in your code ! It helped a lot ! But i am still getting the same error :

Comment: 2019-12-08 21:12:23.046 19983-19983/com.example.dit.hua.ergasia.firstactivity E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "null": syntax error
2019-12-08 21:12:23.052 19983-19983/com.example.dit.hua.ergasia.firstactivity E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting null=32 _FIRST_NAME=dasd _LAST_NAME=dasd
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "null": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO MY_DATABASE(null,_FIRST_NAME,_LAST_NAME) VALUES (?,?,?)

Comment: It was also needed to change the method createEntry from my DBHlper class:

Comment: @StillLearning hmm that's what I have mentioned in the edit above if you have read it . Glad it worked

Comment: @StillLearning The global variable/key AGE is not initialisesed. It's null and thus the error is expected.